# Based on array length create a concat string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

array.length=3 
array2=['[A]','[B]','[C]','[D]'];

based on array.length, i want to create set of string
example, if lenght=3
output= [A][B][C]

example, if lenght=2
output= [A][B]

i tried using for loop but it prints vertically and could not store and append ,I have no idea how to print horizontally,any ideas or help would be really appreciated

my output is

[A]
[B]
[C]
AND Then i store it in variable and tried appending them. I know this is not the best idea

Comment: "i tried using for loop but it prints vertically and could not store and append" - this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @andy I updated the question. I hope you understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log(array2.slice(0, array.length).join(''));
```

Though I don't see any point in having the first array. You could use just `var len = 3;`.

Comment: awesome. That worked bro. I will learn more about slice and join. Thanks alot :)